# Generate model records/fields through an integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I was trying to implement the following but I am getting confused which way to proceed.

In my application. I have a  scaffold for Box with its model, controller and view as well as I have an apple model.

What I would like to do is to ask the user in the new.html.erb of the box "how many apples in the box". The value taken here is an integer and the user clicks a button generate which then generates the number of apple fields for that given number. (This must happen in the same form). After all that then I want to click submit which through accepts_nested_form will take in all the details of the box as well as the generated apple fields.

Is this the use of Javascript or MVC of Rails. Please could someone provide examples if possible.

Cheers

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried MVC, But the fact is that I would like to have the apple fields generated in the same form rather than rendering a new page.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** a Box has Many Apples

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :apples
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :apples, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

You can do this pretty simple by sending a parameters to the new action:

```
http://localhost:3000/box/new?apples=3
```

Then in your box controller (def new) just get the **params[:apples]** and create your apples in the **new** method (action).

```
# inside Box controller
def new
  @box = Box.new
  i = params[:apples].to_i
  i.times { @box.build_apple }
end
```

In your view you need to use the and render for each apple a 'row'.

```
<%= f.fields_for :apples do |apple| %>
   <p>here are the apples</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: params[:apples] will be string.So it should be like i = params[:apples].to_i

Comment: @Rogier, I would like to ask the users to input an integer and collect the value from that rather than assigning a hard coded number. Could I achieve that.
 <%= link_to 'Generate Apple fields', new_box_path(:apple_num => ) %>

Comment: basically you end up with either a JS (jquery call or you need to post the field thru a GET or a POST (as in a form).